# Why isn't my overload::constant sub triggered when I use a string variable?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to [overload constants in regular expressions](https://metacpan.org/pod/overload#Overloading-Constants). Here is my Tagger package:

```
package Tagger;
use overload;

sub import { overload::constant 'qr' => \&convert }

sub convert {
    my $re = shift;
    $re =~ s/\\nom/((?:[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\\s*){2,3}(\\((\\w|\\s)+\\)+?)*)/xg;
    return $re;
}

1;
```

---

Here is the subroutine in which I'd like to trigger the overloading:

```
sub ChopPattern {
    my $string= shift;
    my $pattern = shift;

    if($string =~ m/$pattern/) {
        $string =~ s/$&/ /g;
        return ($string, $&);
    } else {
        return ($string, '');
    }
}
```

---

Here is my test:

```
$test = "foo bar Max Fast bar foo";
($test, $name) = ChopPattern($test, '\nom');
say $test;
say $name;
```

---

If I hardwire the test pattern, `\nom`, in the subroutine's match:

```
sub ChopPattern {
    my $string= shift;
    my $pattern = shift;

    if($string =~ m/\nom/) {
        $string =~ s/$&/ /g;
        return ($string, $&);
    } else {
        return ($string, '');
    }
}
```

the test yields the correct answer:

```
foo bar  bar foo
Max Fast
```

---

But if I use `$pattern` in the match as above the test yields:

```
foo bar Max Fast bar foo
<null line>
```

Is there a reason that `\nom` triggers Tagger but a variable equal to `\nom` doesn't?

Here are the details of the version of Perl being used:

```
This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread (with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)

Copyright 1987-2012, Larry Wall

Binary build 1604 [298023] provided by ActiveState http://www.ActiveState.com
Built Apr 14 2014 15:29:45
```

Comment: Worth a few upvotes, as it never occurred to me that you could overload the regex engine like that.

Comment: @Sobrique: It's possible, but it's not a very nice thing to do. Action at a distance and all that.

Comment: It had also not seen this before. First I thought they misunderstood what `overload` does. But it's actually pretty logical. I just don't really see a use-case for it. It's freaky.

Comment: Can you show exactly what you want your regex to match? I cleaned it up a bit in my answer, but it can probably be simplified more.

Comment: @SinanÜnür that's not an authorized copy?! Args. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Programming Perl* says that `overload::constant` works on constants.

> Any handlers you provide for integer and float will be invoked whenever the Perl tokener encounters a constant number.

When you call `m/$pattern/`, that's not a constant. It's a variable.

> ```
> ($test, $name) = ChopPattern($test, '\nom');
> ```

Now there the `'\nom'` is a constant, but it's a string. Turn that into a `qr//` and you will have a regular expression that contains a constant.

```
($test, my $name) = ChopPattern($test, qr'\nom');
```

The pattern-match in `ChopPattern` can stay the same:

```
if($string =~ m/$pattern/) { ... }
```

Because there now is a constant part in a regular expression, Perl can call your `convert` overload, and do your regex.

---

Let's see this in action. Remember Perl is doing this overloading substitution at compile time, when it parses the source code.

Consider this example:

```
BEGIN {
    overload::constant 'qr' => sub {
        my $re = shift;
        $re =~ s/\\nom/foobar/;
        return $re;
    };
}

sub match {
    my ( $t, $p ) = @_;
    $t =~ m/$p/;
}
match( 'some text', '\nom' );
```

It's not important what the code does. When we deparse it, we get this output:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse scratch.pl 
sub BEGIN {
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use feature 'say';
    overload::constant('qr', sub {
        my $re = shift();
        $re =~ s/\\nom/foobar/;
        return $re;
    }
    );
}
sub match {
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use feature 'say';
    BEGIN {
        $^H{'qr'} = 'CODE(0x147a048)';
    }
    my($t, $p) = @_;
    $t =~ /$p/;
}
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
BEGIN {
    $^H{'qr'} = 'CODE(0x147a048)';
}
match 'some text', '\\nom';                       # <-- here
```

We can see that the handler was installed, but in the last line in the function call, there is the `'\\nom'` string.

Now if we use a quoted expression `qr//` there instead of the string, things change.

```
BEGIN {
    overload::constant 'qr' => sub {
        my $re = shift;
        $re =~ s/\\nom/foobar/;
        return $re;
    };
}

sub match {
    my ( $t, $p ) = @_;
    $t =~ m/$p/;
}
match( 'some text', qr/\nom/ );
```

Now the deparsed program suddenly contains `foobar`. The regex was changed.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse scratch2.pl 
sub BEGIN {
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use feature 'say';
    overload::constant('qr', sub {
        my $re = shift();
        $re =~ s/\\nom/foobar/;
        return $re;
    }
    );
}
sub match {
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use feature 'say';
    BEGIN {
        $^H{'qr'} = 'CODE(0x1e81048)';
    }
    my($t, $p) = @_;
    $t =~ /$p/;
}
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
BEGIN {
    $^H{'qr'} = 'CODE(0x1e81048)';
}
match 'some text', qr/foobar/;                       # <-- here
```

It did that before the code was even run.

If we run both programs with `-MO=Concise` to see what the interpreter will run after compile time, we get further proof that this stuff only works on actual constants in the source code, and cannot work dynamically.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise scratch.pl 
8  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 2529 scratch.pl:5950) v:%,R,*,&,{,x*,x&,x$,$,469762048 ->3
7     <1> entersub[t1] vKS/TARG,2 ->8
-        <1> ex-list K ->7
3           <0> pushmark s ->4
4           <$> const(PV "some text") sM ->5       # <-- here
5           <$> const(PV "\\nom") sM ->6
-           <1> ex-rv2cv sK/2 ->-
6              <$> gv(*match) s ->7
```

And with `qr//`:

```
 $ perl -MO=Concise scratch2.pl 
8  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
1     <0> enter ->2
2     <;> nextstate(main 2529 scratch2.pl:5950) v:%,R,*,&,{,x*,x&,x$,$,469762048 ->3
7     <1> entersub[t1] vKS/TARG,2 ->8
-        <1> ex-list K ->7
3           <0> pushmark s ->4
4           <$> const(PV "some text") sM ->5       # <-- here
5           </> qr(/"foobar"/) lM/RTIME ->6
-           <1> ex-rv2cv sK/2 ->-
6              <$> gv(*match) s ->7
```

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a reason that `\nom` triggers Tagger but a variable equal to `\nom` doesn't?

Because `'\nom'` is a string literal, not a constant piece of a regex:

```
$ perl -Moverload -E'BEGIN { overload::constant qr => sub { say "@_" } } $foo =~ "bar"'
$ perl -Moverload -E'BEGIN { overload::constant qr => sub { say "@_" } } $foo =~ /bar/'
bar bar qq
```

---

What you're doing is a bad idea. The following implementation is much easier to understand and doesn't change regex semantics everywhere:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

sub chop_pattern {
    my ($string, $pattern) = @_;

    my %mapping = (
        '\nom' => qr/((?:[A-Z][a-z]+\s*){2,3}(?:\([\w\s]+\)+?)*)/
    );

    if (exists $mapping{$pattern}) {
        my $matched = $string =~ s/$mapping{$pattern}/ /g;
        return $string, $1 if $matched;
    }

    return $string, '';
}

my ($string, $chopped) = chop_pattern('foo Bar Baz qux', '\nom');
say "<$string> <$chopped>";
```

Output:

```
<foo  qux> <Bar Baz >
```

I'm guessing you went with overload because you want to handle more than one "magic" string (e.g. `\nom`). I did that with a simple hash that maps strings to regexes.